# Unable to register sencha.myget.org with trial version

Tags: extjs

I am trying to configure EXT JS 30 days free trail with below commands:

```
npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/ --scope=@sencha
npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/trial/npm/ --scope=@sencha
```

But im unable to register by showing the specified login is not valid.
I got a mail with the required username and password.

Any help

Comment: Their npm does not work about 1 month.